# How to apply Backtracking in solving Travelling salesman problem?

Tags: java, algorithm, backtracking, traveling-salesman

I've been trying to solve TSP using backtracking.

The question is that I have to print the sequence of  cities which form part of the cycle with minimum cost and its cost.
I don't know how I could save that sequence.

Here is an example of the code I'm trying.

```
public void backTracking(int node, int k, int index) {
    int cost = 0;
    
    while (!isSolution() && hasMoreChild(node)) { 
        solution[index] = node;
        int nextChild = getNextChild(node);
        cost += matrixAdy[node][nextChild];
        backTracking(nextChild, k + 1, index + 1);
        solution[index] = -1;
    }
}


public boolean isSolution() {
    int finalNode = solution[solution.length - 1];
    for (int adyNode : matrixAdy[finalNode]) {
        if (adyNode == start) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't see how a classic backtracking algorithm saves different sequences either.  I guess you can't use backtracking.  That's why we have more than one algorithm for solving these things, there's no universally applicable "it solves everything" solution.

Comment: Could you provide the rest of your code related to the problem? For example, what `isSolution()` does ?

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I have upload that method. The idea is to store all cities in a structure as a array while we are doing backtracking process. So, if we add a city and it wasn't the better option the algorithm has to discard it (at the same time it is computing the cost of the path of the cycle). If you know some kind of implementation I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: Note: I know that the code I posted has bugs, I just want to pass on the idea to get some kind of implementation. If you know of a book related to the topic, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Try looking at [Applying the method for solving  Travelling Salesman problem based on backtracking algorithm to order picking](https://www.scirp.org/journal/paperinformation.aspx?paperid=67515)

Comment: Finally, I managed to solve the problem, it was easier than I thought. Thank you very much.